# Get aapt badging for my android app bundle file

Tags: android, android-app-bundle, bundletool

I am trying to get the aapt badging for my android app bundle file. I know that bundletool has a command to dump the manifest for a file via the command -

> bundletool dump manifest --bundle=my-bundle.aab

The dump manifest command returns the manifest file. I am trying to get the badging for the file similar to what aapt badging offers. Things like supports screens, locales, densities. Is there anyway to get the same?

Example of the apk output for the same -

```
sdkVersion:'4'
targetSdkVersion:'4'
application-label:'MainActivity'
application-icon-120:'res/drawable-ldpi/ic_launcher.png'
application-icon-160:'res/drawable-mdpi/ic_launcher.png'
application-icon-240:'res/drawable-hdpi/ic_launcher.png'
application-icon-320:'res/drawable-xhdpi/ic_launcher.png'
application: label='MainActivity' icon='res/drawable-mdpi/ic_launcher.png'
launchable-activity: name='com.amazon.fooTestLmu1.MainActivity'  label='MainActivity' icon=''
feature-group: label=''
  uses-feature: name='android.hardware.faketouch'
  uses-implied-feature: name='android.hardware.faketouch' reason='default feature for all apps'
main
supports-screens: 'small' 'normal' 'large'
supports-any-density: 'true'
locales: '--_--'
densities: '120' '160' '240' '320'
```

Comment: It doesn't exist for bundles.

Comment: @Pierre So in that case there is no way we can get this information directly from a bundle file is what I gather? Only the basic information like the package version and code?

Are you guys planning to create something in the future?

Comment: You can probably infer a lot of the same data from the "dump manifest" command from bundletool (more than package and version code -- you have all the activities, the permissions, and basically all the attributes from the manifest, etc.). What it doesn't provide directly would be would be locales, densities and paths to icons, which would require an extra "dump resources" command. If that isn't enough, you can file a feature request on bundletool's issuetracker and explain what you need with your use-case: https://github.com/google/bundletool/issues